# Spring Boot container can't connect to Localstack container

Tags: spring, spring-boot, docker, localstack

I'm a **LocalStack/Docker** rookie, trying to create a **docker-compose.yml** file to start a Spring Boot application container + a LocalStack container, I'm not sure if shall I create a network for the containers, and also how to configure the SQS URL in order to make possible to connect my Spring Boot app with SQS running on LocalStack, thanks for your hints.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: my-spring-app
    container_name: spring-app
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      - AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=12345
      - AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=12345
    depends_on:
      - localstack
  
  localstack:
    image: localstack/localstack:latest
    container_name: localstack
    environment:
      - SERVICES=sqs
      - DEBUG=1
    ports:
      - "4566:4566"
    volumes:
      - "/tmp/localstack:/tmp/localstack"
```

**application.yml** (Spring Boot App)

```
cloud:
  aws:
    stack:
      auto: false
    region:
      static: us-east-1
      auto: false
    credentials:
      access-key: 12345
      secret-key: 12345
    queue:
      uri: http://localhost:4566
      name: sample-queue.fifo
```

Comment: There are a few hundred tutorials available to the search "spring boot + docker".

Answer (score 0):

The Uri should be the service name in your `docker-compose.yaml`
In your case:

```
**application.yml** (Spring Boot App)

    cloud:
      aws:
        stack:
          auto: false
        region:
          static: us-east-1
          auto: false
        credentials:
          access-key: 12345
          secret-key: 12345
        queue:
          uri: http://localstack:4566
          name: sample-queue.fifo
```

Answer (score 0):

Compose automatically creates a network for you; you don't need to manually specify `networks:` in your Compose file.  Each service is visible to other containers using its Compose service name as a host name, `app` and `localstack`.  Also see [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation.

You can [set Spring properties using environment variables](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.typesafe-configuration-properties.relaxed-binding.environment-variables) and in a container environment specifying these environment variables is almost always easier than trying to change a YAML file in your application.  You should be able to set:

```yaml
version: "3.8"
services:
  app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    environment:
      - AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=12345
      - AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=12345
      - SPRING_CLOUD_QUEUE_URI=http://localstack:4566  # <-- add this
    depends_on:
      - localstack

  localstack: { ... }
```